# Подсчет символов параграфах - PHP

Tags: php, strlen

Подскажите как подобное реализовать если в параграфе меньше 1000 символов добавить к нему еще несколько, но так чтобы они не объединялись, а шли также параграфом до 1000 символов в общем.

Код выглядит так

```
$str = '
<p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p>
<p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p>
<p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p>
<p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p>
<p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p>
<p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p>
<p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p>
<p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p>';


$caunt = mb_strlen($str,'UTF-8');

preg_match_all('~<p>.*?</p>~', $str, $arr);

$arr = empty($arr[0]) ? [] : $arr[0];


foreach ($arr as $k => $item) {
        echo $item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант (при условии, что все ваши регулярки работают):

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');


$str = '
<p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p>
<p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p>
<p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p>
<p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p>
<p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p>
<p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор.Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p>
<p>К автобусу бежала одевающаяся по поводу чего все вымерли. Пальмой, открыл пасть, засунул в ледяную. Потенцию и взвыл от него была гордая и стал грызть дерево блаженно. Был зажиточный: он сразу женился сзади у поросят находится.</p>
<p>Из-за тучи выглянул луч солнца и упал на двор. Бессмертный хранил свою смерть в горницу вошел. Певчей птицы, кроме вороны стихотворение написано в одном. Королеве подвески, она не пожалел.</p>';


$caunt = mb_strlen($str,'UTF-8');

preg_match_all('~<p>(.*?)</p>~', $str, $arr); 

// $arr[1] is the text without p tag
$arr = empty($arr[0]) ? [] : $arr[1];

foreach ($arr as $k => $item) {
    $tmp_count = mb_strlen($item);
    if($tmp_count >= 1000) // Checking number of characters 
        echo $item;
    else{ // Less than 1000 characters
        // Padding with space
        $new_str = str_pad($item, 1000);
        echo '<p>' . $new_str . '</p>';
    }
}
```

[Подробнее о mb_strlen тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strlen.php)

[Подробнее о str_pad тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-pad.php)